# Angular Column is not Displayed when Toggle is Open

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

In my code, I have a grid list where the user can add a column by sliding a toggle button. The code works fine but when I refresh the page, the column is not there even though the toggle is open. I have to close the toggle and re-open it in order to see the column. Here is my code what should I fix?

[image]

HTML:

```
<mat-slide-toggle [(ngModel)]="this._materialPlan.IncludeAdditionalProduction"
    (change)="toggleAdditionalProduction()" class="mr-8">Ek Üretim</mat-slide-toggle>
```

TS:

```
  constructor() {
    this.initializeGridColumns();
  }

  initializeGridColumns() {

    this.displayedColumns = [
      'Sequence',
      'StockIntegrationCode',
      'ReceiptName',
      'PackagingTheoricYieldQuantity',
      'GeoType',
    ];

    let itemIndex = 0;

    if (this._materialPlan.IncludeAdditionalProduction == true) {
      this.displayedColumns.push("AdditionalProductionQuantity");

    }
    else {
      itemIndex = this.displayedColumns.indexOf("AdditionalProductionQuantity");
      if (itemIndex > 0) {
        this.displayedColumns.splice(itemIndex, 1);
      }
    }

    this.displayedColumns.push("Actions");

  }



 toggleAdditionalProduction() {

    if (this._materialPlan.IncludeAdditionalProduction == true) {
      this.form.controls["AdditionalProductionQuantity"].clearValidators();
      this.form.controls["AdditionalProductionQuantity"].updateValueAndValidity();
    } else {
      this.form.controls["AdditionalProductionQuantity"].setValidators(Validators.required);
      this.form.controls["AdditionalProductionQuantity"].updateValueAndValidity();
    }

    this.initializeGridColumns();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

After toggle happens, you need to call " initializeGridColumns() " to initialize the columns again.

This is based on the explanation you had on your question. Also you dont really show what is the function does upon toggle.

Comment: I edited my code, I actually do call initializeGridColumns()

Comment: have you tried "(ngModelChange)" rather than (change) its more reliable for the use of model. @RocketMonkey

Comment: I tried it now but nothing changed

Comment: just noticed remove the this from the "this._materialPlan.IncludeAdditionalProduction". After that if still no good make sure your variable actually updating. You can achieve that by setting break points or console.log the value. Let me know how it goes. I am out of ideas after that @RocketMonkey

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work as well :/